# Are Omega and Boba genetic twins?

Tags: star-wars, boba-fett, the-bad-batch

Boba Fett and Omega are both unmodified clones of Jango Fett, it seems; does that mean that Boba and Omega are genetically identical? They definitely don't sound or look the same. Plus, Omega is female. Are they genetically identical? If not, what are the differences?

(Obviously, a different gender means different genetics, but could it be that Omega is transgender or nonbinary?)

Comment: In theory for real humans if the Y chromosome could be removed and the X doubled it would be a female clone with all the other chromosomes the same.

Comment: As a pedantic technicality, human sex is determined not by the chromosomes themselves, but by the expression of key hormones at key times, which is *usually* triggered by those chromosomes. It is apparently possible (and observed in real life) to be fully physically male with an XX genome, or female with an XY. I doubt that's a canonical explanation in this case, I just find it fascinating how complicated things can get in real life.

Comment: @IMSoP as seen in this clip from medical drama House. 
(3min mark it gets diagnosed) https://youtu.be/2ry6hn9twow

Comment: Technically, Omega isn't Boba's twin; they're only genetic siblings.  They didn't use the exact same genetic structure; they just made two different unaltered clones of Jango.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No

No, technically, they are not identical. As @lucasbachmann notes, because Omega presumably has two X chromosomes while Boba’s has XY chromosomes, they would not share all their genes; (this science has not yet been so detailed in canon.)

### Maybe

Either Boba or Omega may indeed share 100% of their genes, and one identifies and passes extremely well as a transsexual. This hasn’t been confirmed in canon either, and nine years ago would have been a joke answer, but now and days you never know what Disney might be inclined to do.

Another possibility is that a rare sex disorder could have been engineered or occurred in Boba or Omega. For example, [Swyer Syndrome](https://rarediseases.org/rare-diseases/swyer-syndrome/) would allow Omega to have XY chromosomes, and therefore identically match male Boba while still having female sex organs.

That National Organization for Rare Disorders describes Swyer Syndrome as being:

> Swyer syndrome is a rare disorder characterized by the failure of the sex glands (i.e., testicles or ovaries) to develop. Swyer syndrome is classified as a disorder of sex development (DSD), which encompasses any disorder in which chromosomal, gonadal or anatomic sex development is abnormal. Girls with Swyer syndrome have an XY chromosomal makeup (as boys normally do) instead of an XX chromosomal makeup (as girls normally do). Despite having the XY chromosomal makeup, girls with Swyer syndrome look female and have functional female genitalia and structures including a vagina, uterus and fallopian tubes.

### Sesquizygotic? — Traditional Genetic Twin terminology is impractically misapplied?

Most people know of “fraternal” versus “identical” twins.

Identical twins come from a single fertilized egg. Fraternal twins come from two different ones.

Identical twins happen when a single embryo splits in two soon after fertilization. This is why identical twins have identical DNA. They came from the same fertilized egg.

Since embryo splitting is a random event that happens by chance, it doesn’t run in families. Genes are not involved. The same is not true for fraternal twins.

Fraternal twins happen when two independent eggs are each fertilized by different sperm.  This is why the DNA of fraternal twins is different. In fact, fhe DNA of fraternal twins is no more similar than the DNA any other sibling pair as it is the same biological mechanism which produces both fraternal twins versus other siblings; it’s only a difference of timing. Fraternal twins, and siblings of same parents in general, share about half their genes.

However, there is a rare third category of twinning which probably most accurately defines the genetic relationship between Boba and Omega, established in their case through fantasy alien science rather than occurring naturally:
[sesquizygotic— semi-identical — twins](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.livescience.com/amp/64882-rare-semi-identical-twins.html):

> Twins can be fraternal, identical — and in extremely rare cases — semi-identical. A pair of twins born in January 2014 in Australia share all of their mother's genes, but only 78 percent of their father's, according to a new case report published yesterday (Feb. 27) in The New England Journal of Medicine.
> It's unclear how many other semi-identical, or "sesquizygotic," twins are out there, but it's likely "extraordinarily rare," said lead author Dr. Michael Gabbett, the diagnostic genomics course coordinator at the Institute of Health and Biomedical Innovation in Brisbane, Australia. The first set of semi-identical twins was identified in 2007 in the U.S., when they were infants; this is the first time semi-identical twins have been identified in the womb, according to the report.
> To analyze the fetuses' genes, the doctors took samples of the amniotic fluid that surrounded each twin. (The twins were in separate amniotic sacs in the womb.) This was how they found out that the twins shared 100 percent of their mother's genes but only 78 percent of their father's.
> Normally, a human's DNA comes from two sources: one set of chromosomes comes from the mother's egg and one set comes from the father's sperm. In fraternal twins, two sperm fertilize two separate eggs, yielding twins that share half of their mother’s genes and half of their fathers; in identical twins one sperm fertilizes a single egg, which splits up into the twins that share all of their mother and father’s genes. But in the semi-identical twins, one set of chromosomes came from the egg, and the second set was made up of chromosomes from two separate sperm, Gabbett told Live Science.

In the case of Boba and Omega, they very likely may not share identical genes, but share perhaps as many as every gene being identical except XX/XY chromosomes.

This would put them in a very rare category of being sesquizygotic twins, not quite identical, but sharing excessively more genes than fraternal twins.

Comment: IF the Kaminoans are doing Haploid Meiosis on Jango's cells and then remerging  the daughter cells that's one way to do it.  There might be practical advantages like mitigating telomere shortening that one would think the Kaminoans have solved in standard cloning.  The result would be 100% Jango but with the chromosomes scrambled - which is how normal reproduction works.  But for new trait selection - not  much point to it unless breeding the result with another individual.